# How do I make a service get the updated value of a static variable instead of the default value

Tags: android

I have a service that fetches the value of a value from an activity called "bluetooth", but this activity is started only after the user clicks a button.
In the "bluetooth" class, I have a static variable whose value is updated when the user clicks on a button. But the service is started on launch of the app. So, it takes the default value(0) . I'd like the service to keep on sensing the value of the static variable and update its behaviour on change of the static variable. Please help.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 .......
   bool tr=true;
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {

            while (tr) {
                //check your static variable here

              try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);<-----(1)
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }



            }
          }}
           }).start();
```

put this in your service onCreate..it will check for every 1 second..
you can change the frequency by changing the marked line(1)

Comment: I disagree with this. NEVER use THREAD.sleep in you main thread, it will crash the app soemtimes and will make your app unresponsive

Comment: Sorry.. i didnt remember that.. this is not on mainthread... so i think you can use thread.sleep..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have something like this :

```
...
startChecking();
...



void startChecking(){

   Handler mhandler = new Handler ();
   mhandler.postDelayed( new Runnable(){

      void run(){
        checkStaticValueHere;
        startChecking();
      }
   }, 500);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#Example). Basically, create a method that updates your variable, and make sure you only update your variable thru that method. Then in that method, call the class that needs to be notified of the update thru an update listener.